# Why does n++ and n+1 behave differently in a returned function?

Tags: javascript

I was trying to solve a [LeetCode problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/counter/) where every time a counter is called, the function returns its incremented value.

Problem statement:

> Given an integer n, return a counter function. This counter function
> initially returns n and then returns 1 more than the previous value
> every subsequent time it is called (n, n + 1, n + 2, etc).

My first attempt was:

```js
const createCounter = function(n) {
    return function() {
        return n + 1;
    };
};


 const counter = createCounter(10)
 // Using console.log here to output returned value
 console.log(counter()) // 11
 console.log(counter()) // 11
 console.log(counter()) // 11
```

With this above code I kept getting error and each time the value did not change, got stuck at 11.

I then updated the answer to:

```js
const createCounter = function(n) {
    return function() {
        return n++;
    };
};


 const counter = createCounter(10)
 // Using console.log here to output returned value
 console.log(counter()) // 10
 console.log(counter()) // 11
 console.log(counter()) // 12
```

This was an accepted LeetCode answer.

Can you explain why that is? What is the difference between n+1 and n++ in this case?

I had the right idea but my code was wrong. As soon as I made one little change the code worked, I just want to understan why that is the case, both n++ and n + 1 increments the value, but one continues to work while other get stuck at one incementation.

Answer (score 0):

Please provide the exact question from LeetCode. To use the createCounter function correctly, call it as follows:

```
var createCounter = function(n) {
    return function() {
        return n + 1;
    };
};
createCounter(2)()
```

This is necessary because createCounter returns a function, which must then be called. Keep in mind that the actual value of n (if it were a variable passed to the function) does not change.
For example:

```
let num = 1;
console.log(createCounter(num)()) // print 2
console.log(num) // print 1
```

In this example, there's no difference between returning n + 1 or n++. The minor difference is that with n++, the local variable n is incremented first and then returned. In the case of n + 1, the local variable 'n' remains unchanged. However, the returned value is the same in both cases.

Comment: Your second example is moot. A primitive passed as an argument will never be mutated by operations in the function it is passed to.